# visual studio. Hot key for pasting some specific text

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hotkeys

I Find my self using jquery a lot in visual studio for my current project.  Is there a way to add a hot key that will paste the guts of a selector on the screen?  for example Ctr+shift+J will paste $("#").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a snippet:

[Walkthrough: Creating a Code Snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet)

What this will do is when you type a certain word (lets say selector in this case) and then hit the tab button, it will insert your snippet text that you defined.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it with macros so it works kinda like a hot key command?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the macro solution:

- Record a macro "Ctrl-shift-R"
- Type specified Text (eg $("#").)
- Stop Recording "Ctrl-shift-R"
- Save your recorded macro: Tools-> macros -> save-temporaryMacro
- Assign a shortcut key to your saved marco: Tools -> Options -> Enviornment -> Keyboard

Hope this helps someone. very nice!

Comment: Macros are removed from VS 2012 and newer versions. You may add such functionality with this extension: [Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio)

Comment: @S.Serp awesome, thanks!!! I'll have to give this a try... I've really missed macros once they were removed.